# How to get element back on popBackStack( )

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments: in the first fragment I do it:

```
     ritorno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new SearchFlight()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });
```

and this works well. In the second I need to return to the first fragment, so I decide to do this:

```
 String s = element.getText().toString(); //I need to return it
 FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
 SearchFragment fragment = new SearchFragment();
 manager.popBackStack();
```

I need to return to the first fragment this String. How could I do it? 
Thanks

Comment: [One of the options](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36583226/1815052)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 ways

1. Static Variable : Define `public static` variable in first fragment, update its value in second fragment.
2. [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)
3. [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) you can even find EventBus tutorial [here](http://androidgig.com/eventbus-library-in-android/)

pass string to BR or EventBus and you can fetch it in first fragment by defining appropriate method or listener.

Comment: Why you suggest to use add instead of replace?

Comment: There was some misunderstanding while reading question, sorry for that

Comment: No problem..which of the three method do you suggest? Public static is valid ?

Comment: I would suggest EventBus, after that choice is yours.

Comment: Since the first fragment is removed from the backstack, it probably won't be able to receive the message neither from a broadcast receiver nor EventBus.

Comment: @SqueezyMo I could use also SharedPreferencies?

Comment: I usually use the approach I left in a comment. SharedPreferences is also the option. The recommended way is to pass data through the fragments' common activity. EventBus may work too, depending on how you manage your fragments. So it's up to you.

Comment: Static variable is a terrible idea in this case. It increase the chances of NPE.

Answer (score -3):

Try doing it with a bundle object.

```
 String s = element.getText().toString(); //item to be returned
 FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
 SearchFragment fragment = new SearchFragment();
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString("key", "value");
 fragment.setArguments(bundle);
 manager.popBackStack();
```

And then, in your SearchFragment resolve the bundle like:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
bundle.getString("key");
```

Do the resolution part of the bundle in your onCreateView of the SearchFragment. Do place a null check on the resolution part of the bundle. If the bundle is not resolved, then the getString("key") method will give a null pointer exception.